# Convert a list to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm currently iterating through a dictionary and creating a list of strings, each one composed of a key / value from the dictionary, using this:

```
listA.append(attributesA + " " + thisObjectA.attributes[attributesA])
```

This gives me something like this:

```
['model taurus', 'make ford', 'color white']
```

I need to be able to reference a particular string in the list by index number or possibly by the first few letters in the string. I think what I want to do is use an array instead of a list. Not only will I be referencing multiple strings, from multiple arrays, I'll need to update certain strings with new strings. Would it be better if I used numpy for this?

Could you please suggest the best way to use an array instead of a list for this?

Comment: I don't know why you think an array would be any better for this. Why do you not like the list?

Comment: (Heck, what was wrong with the dictionary?)

Comment: If you are bent on using array only, you can convert it later as `np.asarray(listA)`. Just to answer your particular flavour

Comment: I'm creating the list from two dictionaries. So, I suppose I could have created a new dictionary instead. My main objective is comparing strings (or key/values) from two lists and they'll be in the same index position. If I used dictionary instead of a list, I think i'd need to reference a key/value by key and not position?

Comment: If you have two dictionaries you could just compare the `keys` or `values` of what you are looking for and eliminate this entire process, dictionaries are very useful, maybe post a question on how to get the results you desire using the dictionaries you already have created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method seems fine to me if you are having trouble identifying the index for each one you can use `enumerate` your lists and return the two indexes for the item you are locating.

Although I would recommend staying with the dictionaries, which most likely should be able to accomplish your task

```
lista = ['model taurus', 'make ford', 'color white']

for index, item in enumerate(lista):
    print(f"{item}: {index}")
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 yodish.py 
> model taurus: 0
> make ford: 1
> color white: 2
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I can identify the index of a small list like this by eyeballing it. I'd like to be able to retrieve a string by index number, then retrieve a string of another list (by index number), do some logic and possibly update a string (via index number). In the above example: Get [2], *do something*, replace [2] with 'make chevy'

Comment: As mentioned maybe try a new question with your data and what you want to accomplish I'm sure we will be able to find a solution :)

Comment: but you could use enumerate and do a search `if item in list is something return index` and then use those two indexes from each list

Comment: I think that's basically what i'm looking to do. I wasn't sure if I had to enumerate or if I could go directly to an index position in a list to retrieve something; that's why I brought numpy into the question.

Comment: yeah set up a `for` loop that does something like `if item == 'ford', x = index` and then you cand apply that `index` to your list

Comment: I appreciate the help! I'll keep thinking on this, another question may be in order.

Comment: @yodish Cheers :) I'm sure I'll be around when that gets posted, goodluck!